# Instagram API: do scopes work with OAuth2 implicit authentication flow?

Tags: oauth, scope, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm making requests against the Instagram API from a mobile app. Currently, I'm just directing the user to the Instagram auth url and specifying the response type to be "access_token". Specifying this response_type is known as implicit auth.

Explicit auth: response_type=code
Implicit auth: response_type=access_token

I'm trying to get around needing to stand up a web service to facilitate explicit auth. This would be necessary because in explicit auth flow, the Instagram API needs to make a call to a redirect URL and pass in a "code" parameter. The code would then be used by my server-side code to make a final request to Instagram for an access token.

It's much more efficient for a mobile app to use implicit flow because no extra privately-maintained auth service needs to be stood up to handle it.

Instagram supports the following scopes:

- basic - to read any and all data related to a user (e.g.
  following/followed-by lists, photos, etc.) (granted by default)
- comments - to create or delete comments on a user’s behalf
- relationships - to follow and unfollow users on a user’s behalf
- likes - to like and unlike items on a user’s behalf

When I make any other type of scope specification besides "basic", I get the following response when the user provides the credentials at the auth URL:

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Invalid scope field(s): basic+likes"}
```

Any combination of scopes other than "basic" gives the same response.

So, my question are these:

- **Is explicit auth required in order to specify scopes beyond "basic"??**
- **Do I need to specify response_type=code in order for extended scopes to work?**
- **Is this an Instagram limitation, or is it a limitation of OAuth 2.0?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer here is that **YES**, scopes can be requested by implicit auth flow just fine. My problem was related to an OAuth component that I was using. The component was silently URL-encoding the value of the scope param, which was rejected by the Instagram auth endpoint. I updated the component ([Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth)) to accomodate a non-encoded scope param and issued a pull request.

Thanks to @krisak for providing a working URL that I could test.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Check your browser URL contains something like 'scope=likes+comments' rather than 'scope=likes%2Ccomments' - note that URL encoders often re-encode '+' as %2B.

Answer (score 9):

I just tried with implicit oauth flow with my client_id and scope=basic+likes and it worked. Replace the url below with your client_id and redirect_uri, and try.

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token&scope=basic+likes
```

May be Instagram is not allowing scope other than basic with new client accounts...

Comment: Crappy. That really sucks. And from what I've read, their support emails go unanswered for months.

Comment: I created gramfeed.com, client implicit oauth is not very secure, people are abusing it by collecting access_token from any app using for auto likes/comments, so may be instagram disabled, I can find out and let you know.

Comment: Ahhhh....I see. That could very well be. I can see how it would be abused. That's why I'm thinking if I use explicit (access_token) auth flow, I may be able to get the scopes I want. I guess I'll have to stand up my own proxy auth service so that the mobile code can call it. And yes!, I'd really appreciate it if you could find out! Thanks!

Comment: Just checked out Gramfeed, BTW. Very cool! Another thing I've been noticing about my IG requests...the User.Counts.FollowedBy property is always 0. The other counts (like Follows and Media) are fine, but Followers is always 0. Very strange.

Comment: Just shot you a LinkedIn invite.

Comment: Krisak, you were right...I used the url you provided, replacing my client id and redirect url and this time I was presented with the scope permissions UI. Thanks! Must have formed my URL poorly or something.

Comment: It turns out that my problem is related the Xamarin.Auth component I was using. Xamarin.Auth is essentially just a webview with some stuff to help with handling OAuth. So, I can either roll my own auth UI for Instagram, or I can tear into the Xamarin.Auth source and find the root problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just another note on the problem. The Xamarin.Auth component was URL encoding the scopes parameter. So, what should have been "basic+likes+comments+relationships" in the auth URL was "basic%2Blikes%2Bcomments%2Brelationships". The Instagram auth endpoint did not like this!

Comment: hmm, percent encoded URL should also work, my app sends percent encoded login request and it works, anyways glad u were able to find the issue.

Comment: Weird! I'm not sure why it wasn't working. But yeah, at least it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

So I had similar issues regarding the encoding of the + when trying to get permission for multiple scopes (basic, likes, comments). The solution I found was to use spaces between the individual scopes:

In the config/initializers/omniauth.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :instagram, 'TOKEN', 'SECRETKEY' , {:scope => "basic likes comments"}
end
```

Comment: That's interesting, considering that the Instagram docs specify a "+" between each scope at the bottom of this page: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately starting from April 14th 2015 new clients cannot get access for any scope but **basic**. Official message could be found at the client configuration page:

> Starting April 14th 2015, new clients need to request access to be able to post likes, follows, and comments. For more information please read the Developer Blog at http://developers.instagram.com.

The message refers following blog entry: http://developers.instagram.com/post/116410697261/publishing-guidelines-and-signed-requests

Instagram requires personal request to be sent to enable scopes for your application (client ID), but your app has to meet certain conditions described in the blog entry.

Comment: i saw that recently as well. Crappy. I was planning on using commenting and liking.

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem i found this solution and works fine

Go to Manage clients under instagram/developer. Then click edit under your app and uncheck Disable Implicit OAuth. It will now work as intended.

Instragram changed this for a reason though, so should probably think twice before going public with your app: http://instagram.com/developer/restrict-api-requests/

Comment: Ha! Very cool! That actually makes a lot of sense. Nice find!

Answer (score 1):

At this time, *May 2015*, YES.

As explained on [instagram documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) about authentication:

> The Instagram API uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol for simple, but
>   effective authentication and authorization. OAuth 2.0 is much easier
>   to use than previous schemes and developers can start using the
>   Instagram API almost immediately. The one thing to keep in mind is
>   that all requests to the API must be made over SSL (https:// not
>   http://).

You first need to register your app [**here**](https://instagram.com/developer/) and then, with CLIENT ID provided by instagram, you can do this request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

Where you have to put your client_id and redirect_uri.

Just for information, in redirect_uri field you can insert also

```
http://localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

you must be add "+" between scopes like that is "basic+comments+follower_list+likes+public_content+relationships"