# Adding scopes to instagram app?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to give my app the ability to use other scopes besides the basic permissions, but when I try it with other scopes I get the following error:

> Something went wrong :(stdClass Object ( [meta] => stdClass Object (
>   [error_type] => OAuthPermissionsException [code] => 400
>   [error_message] => This request requires scope=likes, but this access
>   token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize
>   your application with scope=likes to be granted write permissions. ) )

The problem is that when I try to re-authorize the user nothing happens. So I went to the documentation again and it says:

> Note that in order to use these extended permissions, first you need
>   to submit your app for review

But there is nowhere in the developer website where I can see a any submit app link.

Does anyone has any idea how to proceed?
And help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer. It looks like the changed the mechanism. Existing apps are fine till april 28 2015 after that all apps will have to follow new rules here:

http://developers.instagram.com/post/116410697261/publishing-guidelines-and-signed-requests

Answer (score 5):

Your login URL must be like :

> `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxxx&redirect_uri=zzzzzz&scope=basic+likes+comments+relationships`

where ***xxxxxx*** is your client_id and ***zzzzzz*** is your redirect_uri that you had defined in your application ;)

Hope i helped ^^

Comment: Thanks Romdhan, that is the exact URL I am using, still it requires me to re-authorize a user who was previously authorized without the 'likes' scope. But when I visit the URL again nothing happens except the error telling me to submit the app. Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Have you Tried to unsubscribe the user ?

Comment: Yes, no luck, where you able to authorize users for likes without having to review the app?

Comment: No need to modify the application, you must modify the login URL!
Have you tried with another user ?

Comment: Yes, only basic info is appearing as a scope. Here someone else had the same problem but it looks they resolved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580535/instagram-api-do-scopes-work-with-oauth2-implicit-authentication-flow I am checking how.

Comment: My login URL works like a charm, i get all the scopes !

Comment: Yes if your app was created previously will still work till april 28.

Comment: have you guys solved this? i am not getting this to work in sandbox mode

Comment: client_id is access token or no?