# How to get the influencer list on instagram using api?

Tags: php, instagram-api

```
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tagname}?access_token=abacdefg223bjdh"
```

its give the error message like

> This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is
>   not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your
>   application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions.

IN SANDBOXMODE ITS NOT GIVE ANY PERMISSION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the scope when you're requesting the token. You can refer to this answer here: [Adding scopes to instagram app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707126/adding-scopes-to-instagram-app)

Comment: can I see what url you used to request the scope with?

Comment: 'authorization_url'  => 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&scope=basic+likes+comments+relationships',

Comment: The scope is inside that authorization request url right?

Comment: Yes.Its inside the url