# Problems with scope in instagram api

Tags: api, instagram

I created an application on instagram, but when I try to authenticate with this command:
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=35af9cc4c85c40f4adb9370b81568a74&redirect_uri=http://www.minhaminha.com.br&response_type=code&scope=likes

The scope "likes" not appear in autentication window. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram doesn't allow [non-basic scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580535/instagram-api-do-scopes-work-with-oauth2-implicit-authentication-flow) on new accounts, unfortunatelly.